# CSS3 column count overflow hidden issue

Tags: css, overflow

I have an issue with column count. I am using tooltip and parent container cell_wrapper div seems to act like it has overflow hidden.

Firefox worked well from the start, I manager to find fix for chrome by using  transform: translateZ(0); on parent cell div, but it still doesn't work in ie / edge.

```
<div class="cell_wrapper">
  <div class="cell">
      <span class="info" data-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">?</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

If you hover over blue question mark you will see the problem in ie.

https://jsfiddle.net/xjw4Lru2/5/